# Multiple instances of speed dial extension

Tags: opera-extension

Is it possible to install multiple instances of some speed dial extension to provide different speed dials? for example http://addons.opera.com/ru/extensions/details/custom-speed-dial-image/?display=en

Answer (score 0):

In Opera 12, this used to be possible. From Opera 15 onward, this is no longer possible. However, you can download the extension to your hard drive and then drag it to opera:extensions. Duplicate and drag again for every extra instance you need.

Comment: It doesnt work, it add first instance only, it seems to duplicate it is required has different ID of extension

Comment: @KonstantinZaitsev try to unzip and repackage the extension again. Then it should work.